# Delphi resizable bsDialog Form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I make a Form (ShowModal) with BorderStyle `bsDialog`. but one that could still be resized and have the close button (without the Icon,Minimize, Maximize)?

I do not need it to show the size grip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution which seems to work OK:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
  BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
  AutoScroll := False;
end;

procedure TForm2.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME or WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
end;
```

IMO, This cant be done with `bsDialog` but the above feels and looks just like a "`bsDialog`" which could be resized.

Comment: Awesome solution, this has been bugging me for ages.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `BorderStyle` to `bsSizeToolWin`.

Comment: That makes a tool window with a smaller title bar, not a regular dialog box.